# How to retrieve Case Details from CaseHistory object?

Tags: apex, soql, relationships

I can't find the relationship between Case and CaseHistory. CaseHistory doesn't appear in the Schema Builder.

I have the following query in my Apex Class:

`historyList = [SELECT CaseId, CreatedById, OldValue, NewValue, Field FROM CaseHistory ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC LIMIT 20];`

How can I pull back the Case Fields relating to these records?

I've tried the following:

`historyList = [SELECT CaseId__r.Subject , CreatedById, OldValue, NewValue, Field  FROM CaseHistory ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC LIMIT 20];`

and also:

`historyList = [SELECT CaseId, (SELECT Subject FROM CaseId__r ), CreatedById, OldValue, NewValue, Field  FROM CaseHistory ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC LIMIT 20];`

Comment: Accidentally flagged this cause of the dang mobile app. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of relationship query is called a [`Right Outer Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Right_Outer_Join). The correct syntax in this case:

```
SELECT Case.Subject FROM CaseHistory
```

You can get the relationship name using:

```
system.debug(CaseHistory.CaseId.getDescribe().getRelationshipName());
```

Answer (score 1):

Standard object relationship fields truncate the "Id" -

```
[SELECT Case.CaseNumber FROM CaseHistory LIMIT 1]
```